# Get total from child table with parent table Id

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query data from population table from members
table using the first state id (sid), by selecting the first appeared "sid" on members table
for each state id "sid" without duplicating all appeared sid on members table.
I want to get on male and female total for each state using sid. but when I query I get total of all record
from poupulation table

```
Example: 
      male_child(20) + female_cahild(70) for sid = 1
      male_child(10) + female_cahild(12) for sid = 3
      total = 112
```

Here is my sql query :

```
SELECT sum(p.number)as total FROM population p 
JOIN members m ON p.mid = m.mid

states
+------------
|sid | name |
+----+------+
| 11 | A    |
| 23 | B    |
+-----------+

members

+-------------------------+
| mId  | sid  | date      |
+------+------+-----------+
| 1    | 11   | 10-2-2021 |
| 2    | 11   | 15-2-2021 |
| 3    | 23   | 12-2-2021 |
| 4    | 23   | 16-2-2021 |
+--------------=----------+
```

pupulation table

pupulation

```
+----------------------------------------+
| pid | mid | gender | type   | number   |
+-----+-----+--------+--------+----------+
| 1   | 1   | male   | child  | 20       |
| 2   | 1   | female | child  | 50       |
| 3   | 2   | male   | child  | 20       |
| 4   | 2   | female | child  | 20       |
| 5   | 3   | male   | child  | 10       |
| 6   | 3   | female | child  | 12       |
| 7   | 4   | female | child  | 30       |
| 8   | 4   | female | child  | 25       |
+----------------------------------------+

result : getting total / sum of the first `members`.`sid` 11 on row1 and 23 on 
row3 of members table then sum their population
that will be (20 + 50) + (10 + 12) = 92
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And show the results you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually shown what your desired results are, but I suspect you just need to group by the relevant columns

```
select
    s.name, 
    p.gender, 
    Sum(p.number) as total
from population p 
join members m on p.mid = m.mid
join states s on s.sid = m.sid
group by s.name, p.gender
```

**Edit**

To get the desired total, simply get the minimum `id` for each member and `sum` the rows for those IDs

```
select Sum(number) as Total
from population
where mid in (select Min(mid) from members group by sid)
```

Example [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b239cef57c3262cdbf75c265d087450f)

Comment: I want to get only one record matching members sid. for example there are two rows of sid 11,11,23,23 on members table. I want to select the latest record for each member sid and get the total population of the population table. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please add your your desired results to your question for the sample data.

Comment: Ok I'm adding it

Comment: I edited my question. Please check it for me. Thanks

Comment: I tried it but I still get the sum of all records for population instead of 92, I get 187.

Comment: Please see this [working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b239cef57c3262cdbf75c265d087450f). You haven't tagged your specific database, however this works in almost all databases.

Comment: I tried it working. but if I add another data of the same `members`.`sid` the amount still increasing. The intension is to get the top level of every parent `members`.`sid` for each latest mid without getting the sum of all repeating sid for the latest inserted sid on members table